# AWS autoscaling based on uwsgi listen queue

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, uwsgi, autoscaling

I want to add instances to the current setup based on uwsgi listen queue. If uwsgi process have a high backlog, a new machine will spin up and respond to requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the uWSGI alarm subsystem:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/AlarmSubsystem.html

the --alarm-backlog function will trigger an alarm whenever the listen queue is full, this alarm can be an ad-hoc script calling aws api to scale